# Deployment issue using GCP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

since the beginning of the last week we're experiencing an issue with deployment of our service on GCP:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task
/app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2022-11-28T11:42:15.994Z106544.jc.1: 
The region us-central1 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. 
Please try again later.
```

up to that moment we were able to normally deploy our service. Currently we tried to deploy our service during different time of the day, also trying on Sunday. Official recommendation is to switch to another region, however this would mean that we host the service in another location than our DB, making all of the requests much longer.

Did anyone managed to find a reasonable solution solving above issue?

Comment: You are using Flex which is based on Compute Engine. Try choosing a larger instance size.

Answer (score -1):

The demand is high right now. GCP's goal is to make sure that there are available resources in all zones.

As you mentioned  changing the zone and region is actually the best practice other than this you can also refer to these [Best practices](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-use-spot#best-practices).

Another workaround is to  create [Compute Engine reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) when the resources you need are available to reserve them within a zone. Reservations help ensure that resources are available whenever you need them, so keeping reservations of resources you need can help prevent this error.

Rightnow you have to wait for resources or you can use available resources across zones for some period and move to the US central once the resources are available.

Comment: Changing zone and region can't be considered best practice given that GAE doesn't support changing a region and zone once you've created the App. To change Zone & region, you have to create the App again in the new zone/region. Also the essence of using serverless is so that the company (Google in this case) handles resource availability. This means they plan for it. Same company can't then turn around and complain that demand is high

Comment: Look's like the issue with Google App Engine has been resolved for all affected projects can you check now and let us know, Issue has been mentioned in Public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/260280330).